# png image inside WPF button

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, resourcedictionary

Im tring to create a WPF button with a png image inside, but background doesnt works

```
<Setter Property="Width" Value="30"/>
<Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"/>

<Setter Property="Template">

    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

            <Grid>
                <Image Source="../Images/Buttons/logo_30px.png"/>
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

my button size is 30x30 and my image is 30x30 px also and it has transparent regions, when I use the "Background" property, it simply doent works.

How can I make the background color work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ControlTemplate would have to *use* the Background property, somehow like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button"> 
    <Grid> 
        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
        <Image Source="../Images/Buttons/logo_30px.png"/> 
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/> 
    </Grid> 
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `ControlTemplate` tag your are building your own button look. so you need to implement (add) your custom background using `Border` or `Rectangle` and bind its `Backrgound(Border)` `Fill(Rectangle)` property to you Button's Background using `TemplateBinding`.

```
<Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
```

or

`<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>`